# How to tar a file from the specific directory in linux?

Tags: tar

pwd:

```
/home/xxx
```

File present in:

```
/home/a/b/c/d/e/
```

Here I want to tar a directory "e" in pwd (i.e xxx folder).

I tried like this

```
tar -vcf tarfile.tar /home/a/b/c/d/e/
```

But the problem is it compressing all the directories like (`/home/a/b/c/d/e`).
But I need directory "e" should be compressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To skip the parent folders, use the `-C` flag to change `tar`'s working directory.

```
$ tar -C /home/a/b/c/d/ -vcf tarfile.tar e
```